# How to create a GET request with parameters, using JSF and navigation-rules?

Tags: java, jsf, redirect, navigation

Is there a way to create an html link using h:outputLink, other JSF tag or code to create a non faces request (HTTP GET) with request parameters?

For example I have the following navigation-rule

```
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>showMessage</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/showMessage.jsf</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

In my page I would like to output the following html code:

```
<a href="/showMessage.jsf?msg=23">click to see the message</a>
```

I could just write the html code in the page, but I want to use the navigation rule in order to have all the urls defined in a single configurable file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an interesting idea. I'd be curious to know how it pans out in practice.

**Getting the navigation rules**

Navigation is handled by the [NavigationHandler](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html). Getting hold of the NavigationHandler isn't difficult, but the API does not expose the rules it uses.

As I see it, you can:

1. parse faces-config.xml on initialization and store the rules in the application context (*easy*)
2. implement your own NavigationHandler that ignores the rules in faces-config.xml or supplements them with your own rules file and exposes its ruleset somehow (*workable, but takes a bit of work*)
3. mock your own [FacesContext](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html) and pass it to the existing navigation handler (*really difficult to make two FacesContext object coexist in same thread and extremely inefficient*)

Now, you have another problem too. Where are you going to keep the mappings to look up the views? Hard-code them in the beans?

**Using the navigation rules**

Off hand, I can think of two ways you could construct parameter-containing URLs from the back-end. Both involve defining a bean of some kind.

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>navBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>foo.NavBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Source:

```
package foo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class NavBean implements Serializable {

    private String getView() {
        String viewId = "/showMessage.faces"; // or look this up somewhere
        return viewId;
    }

    /**
     * Regular link to page
     */
    public String getUrlLink() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();
        String viewId = getView();
        String navUrl = context.getExternalContext().encodeActionURL(
                extContext.getRequestContextPath() + viewId);
        return navUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Just some value
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return "" + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    /**
     * Invoked by action
     */
    public String invokeRedirect() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();
        String viewId = getView();
        try {
            String charEncoding = extContext.getRequestCharacterEncoding();
            String name = URLEncoder.encode("foo", charEncoding);
            String value = URLEncoder.encode(getValue(), charEncoding);
            viewId = extContext.getRequestContextPath() + viewId + '?' + name
                    + "=" + value;
            String urlLink = context.getExternalContext().encodeActionURL(
                    viewId);
            extContext.redirect(urlLink);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            extContext.log(getClass().getName() + ".invokeRedirect", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**GET**

For a GET request, you can use the UIParameters to set the values and let the renderer build the parameter list.

```
<h:outputLink value="#{navBean.urlLink}">
    <f:param name="foo" value="#{navBean.value}" />
    <h:outputText value="get" />
</h:outputLink>
```

**POST**

If you want to set the URL to a view during a POST action, you can do it using a redirect in an action (invoked by a button or commandLink).

```
<h:commandLink id="myCommandLink" action="#{navBean.invokeRedirect}">
    <h:outputText value="post" />
</h:commandLink>
```

**Notes**

Note that [ExternalContext.encodeActionURL](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.1_01/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#encodeActionURL(java.lang.String)) is used to encode the string. This is good practice for producing code that is portable across contexts (portlets, etcetera). You would use *encodeResourceURL* if you were encoding a link to an image or download file.

Comment: Note that I wrote this answer before JSF2/JEE6 came out. JSF2 adds support for view parameters. Anyone stuck on JSF1.2/JEE5 should consider using Seam.

Answer (score 3):

Tried using PrettyFaces? It's an open-source JSF extension designed specifically to make bookmarkable JSF pages / JSF with GET requests possible.

[PrettyFaces - SEO, Dynamic Parameters, Bookmarks and Navigation for JSF / JSF2](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a form?

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Click to see the message" action="#{handler.outcome}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="msgId" value="#{bean.msgId}"/>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I have ;) but how am I gonna append the request paramters to the query string?

Comment: I don't know about JSF <h:form>, but this is automatic with an HTML <form method="get">.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a commandLink with nested param tags.  This is basically the same as hubbardr said above:

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink value="click here" action="${handler.outcome}">
    <f:param name="msgId" value="${bean.id}" />
  </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Then in your backing bean you need to do:

```
Map requestMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                 .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
String msgId = (String) requestMap.get("msgId");
```

And then do whatever you need to do.