# Howto create a facelet-hyperlink with variable data as parameter?

Tags: jsf, parameters, hyperlink, facelets

I have two facelet-pages: customers.xhtml (with a list of customers) and customer.xhtml for detail-view of just one customer. I use a h:dataTable component inside the customers.xhtml:

```
<h:dataTable var="customer" value="#{customerBackingBean.customers}">...</h:dataTable>
```

Now I want to create a hyperlink for each customer in the table. The hyperlink should navigate to the customer.xhtml . Each customer has a property `primaryKey`, which should tell the customer.xhtml whish customer should be displayed.

How do I do this?
How does it work, if I use two different backing-beans for each facelet-page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I saw you have 0 upvotes - it is a general practice to upvote answers that are useful.

Comment: which you seem to continue ignoring ;)

Comment: i am not registered. it is not possible to vote without being registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<h:commandLink action="customer.xhtml" ..>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener 
         target="#{customerBackingBean.currentCustomer}" 
         value="#{customer}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

- then create a property `currentCustomer` in the bean (with getter and setter)
- reference `#{customerBackingBean.currentCustomer}` in the `customer.xhtml`.

Just be careful with the scopes - you *might* have to use session scope if you use redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Or with a regular hyperlink which creates a `GET` request.

```
<h:outputLink value="customer.jsf">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{customer.id}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{customer.name}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

JSF favors `POST` requests, but you can still use `GET` if you want -- it depends on your need and if the page needs to be bookmarkable. Then you need to get the current customer id from the URL when the customer page is rendered.

See [How to create a GET request with parameters, using JSF and navigation-rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138617/how-to-create-a-get-request-with-parameters-using-jsf-and-navigation-rules)