# JSF not rendered when the url has a parameter

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, servlets, mapping

My problem is that when I for example do this

```
<h:outputLink value="changeinfo.jsf">
                Change name
                <f:param name="change" value="name"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

then the requested url is

```
http://localhost:45054/WMC/user/changeinfo.jsf?change=name
```

My url pattern for the faces servlet look like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Now on the changeinfo page

```
<f:verbatim rendered="#{'bean.param'} == 'name'"> 
NAME 
<h:form id="form1"> 
... 
</h:form>
</f:verbatim>
```

Then on the generated html page I only see the word NAME and not the form. Why is this?

Comment: It should work just fine. The query string won't be tested at all on url pattern match. Your problem lies somewhere else. What JSF impl/version? What webserver impl/version? Have you double, no, triplechecked the URL?

Comment: that url IS matched by that pattern. So you have a problem elsewhere. Check the logs.

Comment: You may want to re-elaborate what you meant with "rendered". The ambiguity of the problem might be in there.

Comment: It is JSF 2.0 and glassfish v3. Right now I am trying to make a navigation case as in link in volothamp's answer.

Comment: I mean that everything like <h:form> .... </h:form> etc. is gone when I look at the "compiled" html page. That page is simply empty.

Comment: You mean, the generated HTML output? The page source? Do you use `rendered` attribute anywhere in JSF code? The condition might be false.

Comment: Okay then the generated html code :) Yes I use rendered, but I have tested that the condition is true. I tried to do this <f:verbatim rendered="cond"> BLA BLA <h:form> ... </h:form></f:verbatim>. Then I can see the BLA BLA but not the form.

Comment: I have just changed the question so that it corresponds to what I am really asking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put JSF components inside a `f:verbatim`, only plain vanilla HTML. Use `h:panelGroup` instead.

Also, get rid of those quotes around the bean property identifier in EL. It would otherwise be treated as a plain vanilla string. You should also put the string comparison *inside* the EL expression.

Summarized:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.param == 'name'}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

---

As an extra hint: you can just access request parameters by `#{param}`. If you don't need it further in the managed bean, then you can also just do so:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{param.change == 'name'}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Darn you BalusC! Always answering JSF questions before I get to! ;P

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: [How to create a GET request with parameters, using JSF and navigation-rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138617/how-to-create-a-get-request-with-parameters-using-jsf-and-navigation-rules)?

The problem is not the extension, but that JSF doesn't support this approach out of the box. If you have to code the [McDowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/304/mcdowell) solution or change web framework using for example [Seam](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Seam+pages.xml).

BTW, JSF 2 will support this style of navigation. Take a look at: [fluent-navigation-jsf-2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/fluent-navigation-jsf-2)